# Trigger DIV container onclick instead inside content

Tags: javascript, html, css, containers

I want to add onclick event on a DIV container.

```
<div id="click_div" onclick="alert('test');" style="cursor: pointer">
     <td id="leftContainer" class="form-basic">
     ...
     </td>
</div>
```

Now I have this code, the `<td>` inside have this css property: pointer-events: none;

So I can not add onclick event on it, but I want this click event on the external `<div>`, so everywhere I will click on the `<td>` space the event will be triggered.
The code I posted here is not working, have you any ideas?

If you have any other idea that allow me to click inside the `<td>` with the no-events property will be ok (I can not change the `<td>` css and properties)

Comment: Add css property `pointer-events: all;` on the `div`

Comment: It doesn't work and the cursor still not a pointer inside the <td>

Comment: If I apply backgrund-color: red; to the div I can not see that color, it means the div is not in the correct position?

Comment: You cannot put a td inside a div, q td is a cell in a table and should be nested inside a tr element which is part of a table.  Why don't you get rid of the div and move the parameters to the td ?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have a div wrapping your `<td>` element? I believe that is invalid HTML markup and can have unpredictable behaviours on different browsers.

From the [MSDN page on the td tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td)

> Permitted parents: A `<tr>` element.

From a few experiments based on the snippet below, if your `<td>` is inside a `div` inside `tr`, then chrome refactors it to move the `div` element outside the table.

The click event is not working because the div is not near the `td` but outside the table somewhere.

Similarly, you can't see the background color being set because the div probably has a zero height (it has nothing inside, the td is inside the table the div is now outside). Set `padding:20px` or a `height` value on a div to see where it is actually appearing. (You can also inspect it in the dev tools if you are using a browser that has one)

```css
td {
  pointer-events: none;
  background: green;
}

div {
  background: red;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <div onclick="alert('Hello')" class="container">
      <td class="inner">
        test
      </td>
    </div>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, this is what's happening, the div still out of the <td>, how can I wrap a td inside a div?

Comment: I don't think that is valid HTML to wrap a td inside a div. It's parent has to be `tr` element. You can set the listener on the `tr` element directly too (if that is an option) - it really depends on what you are trying to do - why do you need a `div`? Can you do without it? etc

Comment: I don't need a div, but I can not find another way to not remove the no-action pointer to the <td> but at the same time can click in that space of view to provide an action (in the <td> I have some inputbox ad buttons that don't have to be triggered, that's why there is pointer-events:none )

My ideas was to wrap in a div with the onclick property

Comment: I see. There are a few ways you could do that 1) Target the CSS `pointer-events:none` specifically only to the children of the td where you want clicks to stop working. or 2) Have an absolutely positioned transparent `div` element inside the td with it's height and width set to 100%. Adding a click listener on that should work. But this is not really in the scope of this question.. A little bit of expermentation should get you through. Feel free to ask another question if it doesn't work even after trying :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, put a `<div>` inside a table is not correct.

You can catch your `<td>` in javascript and loop over them to add onclick events.
Just remember that `document.getElementsByTagName` return a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), so you need to loop over those elements to add an event.

If you can't catch/don't want to - your `<td>` you can grab `<table>` for example or a global `<div>` before your table, you will be able to click everywhere and fire the event.

```js
function Ping(){
    alert("Pong!");
}

function tdClick () {
  var myTags = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  for (var i=0;i<myTags.length;i++){
      myTags[i].addEventListener('click', Ping);
  }
}


function tableClick() {
  var myTag = document.getElementById("my-table");
  myTag.addEventListener('click', Ping);
}

// call tdClick() or tableClick()
tdClick();
```

```css
table {background-color: red; padding: 40px;}
table tr td {cursor: pointer; padding: 20px;border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<div>
  <table id="my-table">
    <tr>
    <!-- A division here is NOT correct -->
      <td>
        <!-- A division here is correct -->
        Text here
      </td>
      <td>
        <!-- A division here is correct -->
        Text there
      </td>
    <tr>
  </table>
</div>
```